# A few reminders: Voting, Flagging, Closing, Reviewing

Tags: discussion, voting, flagging

Part of what makes the Stack Exchange format so great is the built in ability to vote for the quality of content and flag, close and review content that needs more attention.

With this in mind, we need to remember to do some of the following:

#### Voting

The voting system helps to ensure that the good content rises up to the top. Voting for good content helps the community determine what is a good piece of content and what might need some work. Obviously, you can decide what to vote for. For more information on voting, [read the help article](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

#### Flagging / Closing

If you see something that needs attention on the site, you can flag it. This helps the system filter posts into various review queues or alert a moderator to the post. [You can read more about flagging here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). If you have [the privilege to vote to close posts](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) you can vote to close a post instead of flagging it. It takes 5 votes to get a post closed (although a moderator can close it in one vote). If you see a question that matches [one of the close vote reasons](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) cast your vote.

#### Reviewing

Reviewing helps to determine what we should do with a post next. You get to the review queue by clicking the following button:

[image]

By using the review queues, we help to improve posts all over the site in one place. For more information on reviewing, [check out the help posts](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues).

#### Summary

By just using the tools we have a bit more, we can really increase the quality of our site together and build a bigger, better community! If you've got any thoughts on this, please post them below.