# Why does the Community user keep bumping questions?

Tags: support, questions, voting, unanswered-questions

Those of you who regularly browse the site will notice that every now and again, the [Community user](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile) (bot) 'modifies' which bumps it up to the top of the questions list. The questions and answers haven't changed but the bot bumps them anyway.

It will look a bit like this:
[image]
<sub>Ignore the yellow highlight, that's just one of my favourite tags.</sub>

## Okay, the Community user bumps stuff, who cares?

The Community user will bump posts that need attention but it will always tell you what the reason for the bump is. If you go into these questions, you'll see a notice like this:
[image: This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.]

As you can see, the Community user has bumped this post because:

- the question is open and has a non-negative (>0) score;
- there are several answers: at least one answer with the score of 0, and no answers with a score of more than 0;
- no answer has been accepted;
- the question has been inactive for over 30 days.

As I've said in a [previous meta post](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2226/a-few-reminders-voting-flagging-closing-reviewing), voting is integral to ensure quality on our site.

## What should I do when the Community user bumps something?

Check out the reason that the post has been bumped for. If there are answers that need voting on, read them and decide whether you think they're useful or not. Remember, if people get encouraged for their good contributions to the site, they'll stick around and our community will grow. If they spend time writing a great answer and nobody notices, they're more likely to go elsewhere. A downvote is useful to point out where someone may be going wrong. If the post is edited, you will be able to undo your downvote.

---

## Related Reading

[Community user bumping criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/351755).